# SwiftUI on iOS 17: Toolbar NavigationLink 's label problem

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios17

I have a "problem" with my iOS 17 app. My view don't correctly appear like it was before iOS 17 and now only shows the SFSymbol but not the Text.

```
NavigationView {
     ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
          //my body
     }
     .toolbar {
          ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
               NavigationLink(destination: StreakView(dayStreak: viewModel.dayStreak)) {
                    HStack {
                         Text("\(viewModel.dayStreak)")
                         Image(systemName: "flame.fill")
                    }
               }
           }
      }
}
```

The Text is not shown on the screen... Why?

I don't know what to do to fix this problem...

Thank you for your responses <3

Comment: The code should work, I have tested it and it works just fine, [take a look](https://imgur.com/a/vnM7AuX).
You probably have an issue with the ViewModel and the dayStreak variable, can you edit your post and upload the ViewModel code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there may be a potential bug or a deliberate change from Apple. To enable the use of your label as you desire, you must modify the `ToobarPlacement` to either `.principal` or `.status`. Additionally, it is important to note that the `.navigationBarLeading` and `.navigationBarTrailing` properties have been deprecated. Instead, you should use `.topBarLeading` and .`topBarTrailing` as replacements for the deprecated ones.